# How do I fire a jQuery-ui dialog when data on a form has been changed but not saved?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ASP.NET form with two buttons on it (one to save the data, one to continue to the next step), and I'm trying to cause a jQuery-ui modal dialog to pop up when the user clicks "Continue" without first saving. I can't get it to work; it always just goes to the next step anyway. This is a form containing an Ajax TabContainer with TabPanels, which I suspect may be throwing a wrench into the works. Here are relevant parts of my code:

.aspx markup:

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="tabContainerRenewal" runat="server" OnClientActiveTabChanged="GetOrigAddrData" OnActiveTabChanged="tabContainerRenewal_ActiveTabChanged">
  <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tabVerifyAddress" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" OnLoad="tabVerifyAddress_Load">
    <HeaderTemplate>Step 2: Address Verification</HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
      <table class="bordered">
        <tr>
          <th class="rightAlign">Company:</th>
          <td colspan="2"><asp:TextBox ID="tbxCompany" runat="server" Columns="50" CssClass="editAddress"></asp:TextBox></td>
          <th class="rightAlign">Position:</th>
          <td colspan="2"><asp:TextBox ID="tbxPosition" runat="server" Columns="50" CssClass="editAddress"></asp:TextBox></td>
...
      <div class="buttonRow">
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateInfo" runat="server" Text="Update My Information" OnClick="btnUpdateInfo_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnContinueNoUpdate" runat="server" Text="Continue" OnClick="btnContinueNoUpdate_Click" OnClientClick="return ContinueNoUpdateCheck(this);" />
      </div>
```

Javascript/jquery functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Check to see if user has changed any address data when continuing without update and
  //  display a dialog if they have
  var continueConfirmed = false;
  function ContinueNoUpdateCheck(obj) {
    if ($('.editAddress').serialize() != origAddrData) {
      var changeTitle = "Data has been changed";
      var changeText = "You have updated information on this form. Are you sure you wish to continue without saving?";
      //add the dialog div to the page
      $('body').append(String.Format("<div id='changeDialog' title='{0}'><p>{1}</p></div>", changeTitle, changeText));
      //create the dialog
      $('#changeDialog').dialog({
        width: 400,
        height: "auto",
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        close: function (event, ui) { $('body').find('#changeDialog').remove(); },
        buttons: {
          'Yes, continue without saving': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            continueConfirmed = true;
            if (obj) obj.click();
          },
          'No, let me save': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
          }
        }
      });
    }

    return continueConfirmed;
  }

  //Get original address form data for comparison
  function GetOrigAddrData() {
    //First find out which tab we're on; we're only concerned with tab 1 (verify address)
    //  get TabContainer object
    var container = $('<%= tabContainerRenewal.ClientID %>');
    switch (container.ActiveTabIndex) {
      case 1:
        var origAddrData = $('.editAddress').serialize();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
</script>
```

"String.Format" is a Javascript function that I wrote in a separate file; I use it all the time, so I know it isn't the problem.

The C# code isn't very interesting at all:

```
protected void btnContinueNoUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //User has elected to not change any data, so we simply advance to certification
  //  without validation (disable address verification tab)
  AdvanceToNextTab();
} //end method btnContinueNoUpdate_Click

protected void AdvanceToNextTab()
{
  //Advance to the next tab in the TabContainer
  //Total number of tabs in container
  int tabCount = tabContainerRenewal.Tabs.Count;
  //Index of currently active tab
  int currTab = tabContainerRenewal.ActiveTabIndex;
  //Advance if we're not already on the last tab
  if (currTab < tabCount - 1)
  {
    tabContainerRenewal.ActiveTabIndex = currTab + 1;
    tabContainerRenewal.Tabs[currTab + 1].Enabled = true;
    //Disable the tab we were just on so they can't go back
    tabContainerRenewal.Tabs[currTab].Enabled = false;
  }
} //end method AdvanceToNextTab
```

So, any ideas? I've been working on this all day, with no success.

Here's a screen shot for context...
[image: renewal screenshot]

Comment: So is it not even showing the modal box?

Comment: I see a bunch of stuff that I would probably do differently, but it's hard to tell what might actually be causing you problems, and what is just the method I personally am used to. (if that makes any sense).

Comment: No, it isn't showing the modal box; importantly, it does if I comment out the line that's comparing the (serialized) form data with the original form data.

Comment: I've never used serialize. Why don't you try calling the serialize method of that element in the console and seeing if it returns undefined.

Comment: I haven't tried this out yet (I was off today), but I think I know what the problem is. It's the scope in which I'm declaring "origAddrData"; it needs to be a global so that the other function can read its value, and it is currently defined only within the function "GetOrigAddrData". I'll let you know after I've checked this.

Comment: OK, that was *part* of the problem. Now the real problem is that the OnClientActiveTabChanged event of my TabContainer control simply isn't firing, or doesn't seem to be. I've scoured the Web for this problem, and haven't found any useful answers. I've found many possible solutions for the server-side ActiveTabChanged event not firing, but the client-side event seems to work for everyone but me.

Comment: The issue is most likely in your GetOrigAddrData function. You can use Console.Log(someVariable) to log objects,variables...well, anything really...to the console. Additionally, if you debug the code in Internet Explorer, you can place breakpoints in the javascript code. You have to use IE though,  otherwise they don't work unless they are in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up dropping the idea of serializing the data for comparison; I just couldn't get it to work. Instead I opted for a solution that iterates through the form elements, comparing each element's `.value` property to its `.defaultValue` property (for text elements); for checkboxes, I use the `.checked` and `defaultChecked` properties, and for select elements I use `.selected` and `.defaultSelected`. Here's the function that checks for changes:

```
function HasFormDataChanged(elemArray) {
  var elemCount = elemArray.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < elemCount; i++) {
    var elem = elemArray[i];
    if (elem.type == "text" || elem.tagName == "TEXTAREA") {
      if (elem.value != elem.defaultValue)
        return true;
    }
    else if (elem.type == "checkbox" || elem.type == "radio") {
      if (elem.checked != elem.defaultChecked)
        return true;
    }
    else if (elem.tagName == "SELECT") {
      var options = elem.options;
      var optsCount = options.length;
      for (var j = 0; j < optsCount; j++) {
        var opt = options[j];
        if (opt.selected != opt.defaultSelected)
          return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```